# Cloudflare Status API - which component to check for issues?

Tags: cloudflare

SUMMARY: the Cloudflare Status API returns info on 100s of components, which one tells me if there's a real issue?

DETAIL (if you want/need it): we serve our static content off assets.mydomainname.co.uk, which points to Cloudflare. When Cloudflare goes down, we lose that content and must switch back to serving it from www.mydomainname.co.uk (manually, at the moment).

Following the 2 recent Cloudflare outages I'm developing a component to check the Cloudflare Status API every 5 minutes via cron, and if an issue is found that would affect CF's ability to serve my content, then my site will switch to serving content from my own servers. This beats the hell out of being woken up at 4am and having to switch to local serving manually.

The Cloudflare Status API is trivial to access, and includes a summary indicator that can say 'none', 'minor', 'major' or 'critical'. If there's a major or critical issue then I'll switch to local serving. If it returns 'none' then I know I'm good to keep serving from CF. If it's minor, however, then this could indicate that (as of right now, for example) there's just an issue with cache purging that isn't really going to affect CF serving my static content for me...OR it could indicate a minor issue that's affecting my site and I do need to switch to local serving.

Problem is the status API returns a *lot* of information on components. There are hundreds of them. Which one do I check?

(The alternative, of course, is just to test a few Cloudflare URLs and see if they return a 2** or 3** code rather than a 4** or 5** code, but this seems inexact and inelegant when there's a purpose built API to use).

Comment: Looks like this is going to have to be a trial and error basis. Have got the system up and running looking for major and critical outages only, they also publish an 'all CF sites and services' summary component in the API response which I'll monitor for partial or total outages during office hours only, so I can manually correct false positives until I get to a solution which works by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components describe the region Cloudflare operates in (Africa, Asia etc), the individual PoP (point of presence/data center) within the region, as well as actual Cloudflare sites and services within Cloudflare (billing, DNS, dashboard, analytics etc).

If you are mostly using Cloudflare for DNS and caching the static assets only, I believe you may want to look at DNS related services, as well as the PoPs or regions where most of your traffic is coming from.

Outage at a global scale rarely happens, but if that's what you're looking for then you may want to check for all the components.

Maintenance and incidents are more likely to happen on a smaller scale, impacting specific data centers or services.
If Singapore traffic were rerouted to Hong Kong due to a fiber cable cut or routing issue in Singapore for example, your visitors in Singapore will be experiencing slight latency because the cache will be served from Hong Kong instead.
Unless your website depends on low-latency network (global financial trading or high performance gaming for example), it should not cause that huge impact to your business.

If you do operate at that low-latency level however, consider upgrading to the Enterprise plan because they do prioritize their Enterprise customers more when the resources became scarce, and will not hesitate to route the free and lower-tier plan's traffic away to other data centers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll start with the DNS related services, and see if they generate false positives for my site being down with partial outages.

Comment: it's an awesome project. any chance to open-source it on github?

Comment: Everything apart from a basic cUrl request is fairly specific to our setup, so there wouldn't really be much value there for other people.